# Channel creation failed at test network of hyperledger fabric

Tags: testing, networking, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, peer

When i run test network at hyperledger fabric i have this error
rror: Post "https://localhost:7053/participation/v1/channels": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:7053: connect: connection refused
Channel creation failed
How to solve it

Comment: hi do you solve the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Try downloading again the test network from Github repository and start the network again. Sometimes, when the test network is stopped, it stores some annoying files. By redownloading the test network, you will start with a clean network.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: can you guid me how to do that @user17014405

Answer (score 1):

### Renaming current folder and Re-downloading the sample worked.
Could be a issue with port or prior version

Here are details steps to cleanup prior sample which worked for me
Step 1) run following
./network.sh down

Step 2) docker ps
Validated that all containers are gone.

docker ps --all

Step 2.b) Incase if you still see containers, use following
Note the first letter of the container ID from 'docker ps --all' command
e.g 20c0e323a69   hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest
Run following
docker rm 2

it will remove 20c0e323a69
Do the same for all containers

Step 3) Renaming the folder steps
Go back to the root directory
Rename the folder by running following. or just delete if you dont have any custom scripts

$ mv fabric-samples oldfabric-samples

Step 4 ) reinstall by running following
"$ curl -sSL https://bit.ly/2ysbOFE | bash -s -- 2.2.2 1.4.9"
or follow steps in  https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/test_network.html

Step 5) List of following command
cd fabric-samples/test-network
./network.sh down
./network.sh up
docker ps -a

Step 6)./network.sh createChannel
Above should work now

Assuming you are in the following folder
fabric-samples/test-network

---

Additional Learnings --under the hood
use vscode to view network.sh '$ code network.sh' and look for line scripts/createChannel.sh
if needed, navigate to scripts/createChannel.sh from vscode for more info

Comment: Thank you  for your response

Comment: hi ! I don't understand step 3 ( how to do that ? and why is that ?)

Answer (score 0):

Even this happened two years ago, I would recommend other way to resolve this problem, which recently happened again. Actually, I face this after my computer rebooted because of automatic upgrade, which might be related to this occurence. Remove docker images of hyperledger fabric and install them the same version.

1. ./network.sh down
2. docker rmi -f $(docker images -qa)
3. ./install-fabric.sh --fabric-version X.X.X docker

For 3rd step, you refer to the installation step in https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html. First